# How to wrap text using CSS?

Tags: css, word-wrap

```
<td>gdfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</td>
```

How do I get text like this to wrap in CSS?

Comment: Not CSS so not an answer but using a text field to hold it...just saying

Comment: Eugh. Inputs are there to display input. I thought we had managed to get beyond lying about semantics for presentational purposes.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try doing this. Works for IE8, FF3.6, Chrome

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 100px">gdfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This was not working for me, but @Stirling's answer below did work.

Comment: tested it myslef and it works great! i assume that the only "problem" here, is that you have to set manually the size of the container (100px in this example)

Comment: This also works:

.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

Comment: freaking tables, always solve the issues!

Comment: Use "word-break: break-all;" to avoid mentioning "width".

Answer (score 137):

If you type  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
this will produce:

```
AARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
G
```

I have taken my example from a couple different websites on google.  I have tested this on ff 5.0, IE 8.0, and Chrome 10.  It works on all of them.

```
.wrapword {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}

<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:400px">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapword"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I added "word-wrap: break-word;" but didnt work neither in Firefox nor in IE(I tested only in these two)... n when I added all the option you suggested.. it worked... Thanks!!!

Comment: I had to add "white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;" to get new versions of Chrome (and probably Safari) to work.

Comment: thanks, it worked! bootstrap was doing a thing on its own, and nothing helped. Finally the right solution for me.

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` works

Answer (score 1):

With [text-wrap](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-wrap0), browser support is relatively weak (as you might expect from from a draft spec).

You are better off taking steps to ensure the data doesn't have long strings of non-white-space.

Comment: "To avoid some display error, please do not input long words." Is that really your answer?

Comment: @SandRock — No, it isn't. That is a mischaracterisation of *half* of this answer. The data in the question, while being a "long string of non-white-space" was not a "word". "taking steps" also doesn't mean "don't input", we don't know where the data is coming from, it could mean testing user input for sanity and displaying an error message for inappropriate content.

Answer (score 1):

This will work everywhere.

```
<body>
  <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td><div style="word-wrap: break-word; width: 100px" > gdfggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better option if you cannot control user input, it is to establish the css property, **overflow:hidden**, so if the string is superior to the width, it will not deform the design.

**Edited:**

I like the answer: "word-wrap: break-word", and for those browsers that do not support it, for example, IE6 or IE7, I would use my solution.

Comment: If you're going to use this option be sure to set a width for the element containing the text or overflow:hidden will simply hide the overflow, not wrap it.