# How to change format of long text in cell?

Tags: html, css, format, tablelayout

How can one change the text from displaying like abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz in a cell to :
abc
def
ghi
...?
I can either hide some of the text (abcdef...) or make it appear as a verry ugly long cell.
I would like to do so in HTML or CSS. I already tried playing with line-height, height, display,...
Example code:     http://jsfiddle.net/9jwMZ/1/ (I am referring to the Message column).
For example, why isn't this code working?:

```
table.DataTable tr {
    line-heigth: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You would need to add some spaces to the text, maybe with javascript or from the server, and remove the `white-space: nowrap` property to the `td` declaration. The problem is with the file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/leemeador/9jwMZ/7/

I got the CSS from here: [How to wrap text using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949762/how-to-wrap-text-using-css)

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
```

I also removed your fixed width on the TD and fixed height on the TR

Comment: Exactly like I wanted it to appear! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To force table cell contents to wrap, apply `table-layout: fixed` to the table and `word-wrap: break-word` to the td.

Additionally, if you'd like the cells to have a fixed vertical height and scroll when they overflow, wrap your td contents in a div with `overflow: auto` and `max-height: 100px`.

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jwMZ/6/