# How to fit table rows that are too big for page display?

Tags: html, css

I have a table:

```
    table.tablesorter {
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;


}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #04659D;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0F5E76;
    border-left: 1px solid #0F5E76;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:left;
    padding: 5px 19px 5px 9px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Some of the text in the table  is too big and is being cut from the page, I have try using `word-wrap:break-word;` and setting width but nothing its working the text still overflows?

Any tips on how i can fix this?

Comment: have you tried playing with `font-size` or `line-height`? might be useful to post the output somehow, maybe using jsfiddle...?

Comment: i did try to do it on jsfiddle but i cant get it to show with the overflow

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6fLTt/

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get it to show"? Do you mean it works in JSFiddle and doesn't on your own site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap text using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949762/how-to-wrap-text-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Give your `table` element a [fixed `table-layout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout):

```css
table.tablesorter {
    ...
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

From the CSS2.1 specification (linked above):

> 17.5.2.1 Fixed table layout
>
> With this (fast) algorithm, **the horizontal layout of the table does not depend on the contents of the cells; it only depends on the table's width, the width of the columns, and borders or cell spacing.**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give this a try: I added the word inside a div and gave it a fixed width plus the word wrap, and it worked for me:

```
<div id="test">#DecimalFormat(total/counter)#</div>
```

```css
#test {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width:40px;
}
```

**[Here is your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fLTt/1/)**

**EDITED**: While my suggestion works perfectly in the above demo, if it doesn't work in your specific case, you may need to do some cleanup of your code and maybe use `!important` as a workaround (ie. `word-wrap:break-word !important; width:40px !important;`), or try adding `display:block` - that might help too.

Comment: what do you mean by "didn't work"? have you had a look at the demo? the word is wrapped, isn't that what you wanted? what was it then...?

Comment: yes i look at the demo and try it on mine and it doesnt fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

What is the markup of your table? Perhaps your table's width isn't wide or tall enough to compensate for the auto-adjusting nature of the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a scrollbar to the cells that have too long words.

```
just add the following:

table.tablesorter tbody td {
    max-width: 250px;// you can use any width you like, the scrollbar will show up only when a cell exceeds the max-width.
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

another option would be to use `white-space: normal`, see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

for example

```
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

If this does not work to wrap your text inside a cell, you should check your source and see if there is anything that overwrites your css and fix it.