# Wrap the lines according to the width of first line

Tags: html, css

I have a link with main title and description, and I would like to wrap the description line according to the width of the first line. Can I achieve that by using only CSS?

I have following code:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <span class="ht">Oficiální stránky</span>
  <span class="hb">Podívejte se na oficiální web festivalu</span>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/9uh24zns

Desired output:

[image]

Note: there will be more links in the line with different width of the first bold title.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949762/how-to-wrap-text-using-css

edit: I see that's not exactly what you're doing. But that is the CSS that would wrap your sub-header.

Comment: Nope, but I don't want to set the width manually. It has to be done automatically (my clients can change the menu items themselves and there are more items than one)

Comment: you need javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the CSS `table` + `table-caption` solution.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}
.hb {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<a class="container" href="#">
  <span class="ht">FIRST LINE</span>
  <span class="hb">second line some example content here</span>
</a>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kyr9r1dp/)**

Comment: This is a good alternative but there are some interesting effects - https://jsfiddle.net/qn0gj95n/ :)

Comment: True, as it's caption, but it can be done with applying borders to both of them - https://jsfiddle.net/qn0gj95n/2/

Comment: Thanks, very interesting and quick solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's *sneaky* way of achieving this effect.

```css
.limit {
   border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
  
}

.ht {
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap; /* stop text wrapping */
}

.hb {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="limit">
  <span class="ht">Oficiální stránky</span>
  <span class="hb">Podívejte se na oficiální web festivalu</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use

> word-wrap property but None of the major browsers support the text-wrap property.

```css
.ht {
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.hb {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 18px
}
#wrapDiv{
  width: 190px;
  word-wrap: normal
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapDiv">
  <a href="http://google.com">
  <span class="ht">Oficiální stránky</span>
  <span class="hb" >Podívejte se na oficiální web festivalu</span>
</a>
</div>
```

You can also refer, it's same as [How to word wrap text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147877/how-to-word-wrap-text-in-html)