# How do I get text to wrap in Wordpress theme Mystique 2.6-wpcom?

Tags: css, wordpress, word-wrap

I don’t have great eyesight and have to enlarge text in my browser to read and edit itcomfortably, but apparently text in the Mystique theme does not wrap, so enlarging it just truncates every sentence on the right side of the browser. Can I modify Mystique to make the text wrap? Or do I have to change themes?

If a CSS change is required, then what is it?

Most internet articles about CSS and text wrapping address the problem of [very long words]. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949762/how-to-wrap-text-using-css). That's not my problem. My problem is that in the Wordpress theme I am using, text does not wrap *at* *all*.

If there is no text wrapping fix for Mystique, how difficult is it to port a Wordpress website to a different theme? I’ve already done a lot of work on the articles in the site and don’t want to start from scratch.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to talk to the developers of the theme, they'd be in the best position to advise. This is a very specific issue with a very old theme (I see on themeforest its not been updated since 2016!) so you're unlikely to get the expertise you need here.

Comment: With regard to switching themes - it depends entirely on the themes in question. If your theme uses custom fields (which many do), then the information will remain in the database, but because they are not standard the new theme won't know they're there to display them. If you don't really use the custom fields (e.g. it's mainly blog posts that use the standard text editor & featured image) you might be able to switch without too much extra work. You can usually switch to a new theme, and if it doesn't work, switch back with no issues - but again it depends on the theme.